# Ocaml modules implementation

Tags: ocaml

Ocaml's standard library contains various modules: `List`, `Map`, `Nativeint`, etc. I know that interfaces for these modules are provided (e.g. for the [List module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html)), but I am interested in the algorithms and their implementations used in modules' functions.

Where can I find that?

Answer (score 19):

- On your system: `/usr/lib/ocaml/list.ml` and other `.ml` files
- On the web: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/list.ml and other `.ml` files in https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/tree/trunk/stdlib

---

The List implementation is interesting to study. For example, the `map` function could be implemented like this:

```
let rec map f = function
  | [] -> []
  | a::l -> f a :: map f l
```

but is instead implemented like this:

```
let rec map f = function
  | [] -> []
  | a::l -> let r = f a in r :: map f l
```

What's the difference? Execute this:

```
List.map print_int [1;2;3] ;;
map print_int [1;2;3] ;;
```

The first one prints 123, but the second one prints 321! Since the evaluation of `f a` could produce side effects, it's important to force the correct order. This is what the official map implementation does. Indeed, the [evaluation order of arguments is unspecified in OCaml](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora029.html) even if all implementations follow the same order.

See also the [Optimizing List.map post on the Jane Street blog](https://blogs.janestreet.com/optimizing-list-map/) for considerations on performance (`List.map` is efficient on small lists).

Comment: Thumbs up !

(Here is the blog post, but I find it a bit too arcane for a beginner: http://ocaml.janestreet.com/?q=node/71 )

Comment: Can anyone clarify the difference between the first and second implementations? When I run them in OCaml and F# I receive 123 for both, never 321. Since this answer is 7 years old, maybe OCaml and F# fundamentally changed, but I doubt it? (I'm not using List.map, I'm testing the two custom map functions as-is)

Comment: @gasche Any idea?

Comment: I can reproduce the fact that `ignore (map print_int [1;2;3])` will print 321 for recent versions of OCaml with the `f a :: map f li` version of map. @jayphelps, something may be wrong with your testing setup.

Comment: @gasche Thanks! jayphelps asked his own question, which led to more discussions about this issue (especially in comments): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882340/re-implementing-list-map-in-ocaml-f-with-correct-side-effect-order

Comment: @gasche yeah the inconsistency was the REPL evaluated them in a different order--but my fundamental issue was not realizing OCaml (unlike F# and SML) does not guarantee the evaluation order. It's "unspecified"

Answer (score 5):

You can find the definitions in the OCaml source code.  For example, implementation of the `Map` functions is in `stdlib/map.ml` in the OCaml source distribution.

Answer (score 4):

They should already be installed on your system.  Most likely (assuming a Unix system) they are located in /usr/lib/ocaml or /usr/local/lib/ocaml.  Just open any of the `.ml` files.