# Re-implementing List.map in OCaml/F# with correct side effect order?

Tags: f#, ocaml

According to [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3984750/1770633)

You could implement `List.map` like this:

```
let rec map project = function
  | [] -> []
  | head :: tail ->
      project head :: map project tail ;;
```

but instead, it is implemented like this:

```
let rec map project = function
  | [] -> []
  | head :: tail ->
      let result = project head in
      result :: map project tail ;;
```

They say that it is done this way to make sure the projection function is called in the expected order in case it has side effects, e.g.

```
map print_int [1;2;3] ;;
```

should print `123`, but the first implementation would print `321`. However, when I test both of them myself in OCaml and F#, they produce exactly the same `123` result.

(Note that I am testing this in the OCaml and F# REPLs--Nick in the comments suggests this might be the cause of my inability to reproduce, but why?)

What am I misunderstanding? Can someone elaborate *why* they should produce different orders and how I can reproduce? This runs contrary to my previous understanding of OCaml code I've written in the past so this was surprising to me and I want to make sure not to repeat the mistake. When I read the two, I read it as exactly the same thing with an extraneous intermediary binding.

My only guess is that the order of expression evaluation using cons is right to left, but that seems very odd?

---

This is being done purely as research to better understand how OCaml executes code, I don't really need to create my own `List.map` for production code.

Comment: I just tested both of those implementations of `map` in OCaml and got `321` and `123` as output respectively. Are you running these in the REPL?

Comment: @NickZuber yes I am! Tested in OCaml and F# REPLs as well as BuckleScript online REPL. When I get home I'll try it not using a REPL, but my next question of course is why that would make a difference  and still why the two are not equivalent :)

Comment: Note that the F# implementation of `List.map` in FSharp.Core is actually using mutation under the hood to create the `List` object before returning it, so it can't overflow the stack. The `List.map` examples above are all just examples, and would overflow the stack if they were used as-is. I don't know what the OCaml implementation is doing under the hood, but it probably uses a similar trick so as to not overflow the stack on long lists. You almost certainly know this already, @jayphelps, but I thought it was worth mentioning for anyone else who might come across this question later on.

Comment: @rmunn Great anecdote. In fact, in OCaml `List.map` is quite literally implemented in above example way--not tail-recursive and can indeed blow the stack https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/908a38182752f4052289f661643ee28cc9a6f056/stdlib/list.ml#L80

Comment: @rmunn also important to know: unlike OCaml, in F# function application order is specified and deterministic https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/tests/fsharp/core/apporder/test.fsx (I confirmed with a couple of guys on the F# team)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So when you have an implementation of `map` like this:

```
let rec map f = function
  | [] -> []
  | a::l -> f a :: map f l
```

none of the function applications (`f a`) within the `map` calls are guaranteed to be evaluated sequentially in the order you'd expect. So when you try this:

```
map print_int [1;2;3]
```

you get the output

```
321- : unit list = [(); (); ()]
```

since by the time those function applications weren't executed in a specific order.

Now when you implement the `map` like this:

```
let rec map f = function
  | [] -> []
  | a::l -> let r = f a in r :: map f l
```

you're *forcing* the function applications to be executed in the order you're expecting because you explicitly make a call to evaluate `let r = f a`.

So now when you try:

```
map print_int [1;2;3]
```

you will get

```
123- : unit list = [(); (); ()]
```

because you've explicitly made an effort to evaluate the function applications in order.

Comment: Wow. So this differs from SML, right? This whole time I never realized application evaluation was non-deterministic. Mind=blown.

Comment: @jayphelps Yeah there are definitely a few gotchya's like that — Jeffery has [a great reference to the docs](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html) regarding this behavior if you're interested in reading more about it too

Comment: "none of the function applications (like `f a`) are being executed until the entire function finishes" is wrong. `f a` is certainly evaluated before the `map` call that contains it. The point is that it might not be evaluated before its "sibling" `map` call on the rest of the list.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Thank you for pointing that out — I've revised my answer

Answer (score 11):

The point is that the order of function application in OCaml is *unspecified*, not that it will be in some specific undesired order.

When evaluating this expression:

```
project head :: map project tail
```

OCaml is allowed to evaluate `project head` first or it can evaluate `map project tail` first. Which one it chooses to do is unspecified. (In theory it would probably be admissible for the order to be different for different calls.) Since you want a specified order, you need to use the form with `let`.

The fact that the order is unspecified is documented in [Section 6.7](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html) of the OCaml manual. See the section **Function application**:

> The order in which the expressions expr,  argument1, …,  argumentn are evaluated is not specified.

(The claim that the evaluation order is unspecified isn't something you can test. No number of cases of a particular order prove that that order is always going to be chosen.)

Comment: I see you edited your answer, it's much better now but I had already accepted Nicks. Thank you for taking the time! My mind was blown, I had no idea OCaml application eval was non-deterministic. Can you confirm whether this differs from SML? I swear SML was deterministic on this....then again, I thought OCaml was too HAH

Comment: (Sorry, I often edit my answers after submitting them.) I suspect application order *is* specified in SML, it feels like it would be. But somebody more knowledgeable than me will surely answer your new SO question about it. I'll be interested to see what they say.

Comment: Me too! Thanks again!

Comment: Usually, OCaml starts with the right-to-left evaluation order, but due to optimization, the evaluation order may be arbitrarily disturbed, and even become non-linear, e.g., 1,4,2,3. For example, read the following dramatic story:  https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/966

Comment: Thus, the only way to force the evaluation order is to use `let` bindings and application operators `(|>)` and `(@@)`. But in general, if you're not concerned with the order, it is better to leave more freedom to a compiler.